# How many ways to convert bitmap to string and vice-versa?

Tags: java, android, bitmapdata

In my application i want to send bitmap image to the server in the form of string, i want to know how many ways are available to convert a bitmap to string. now i am using Base64 format for encoding and decoding, it takes little bit more memory. is there any other possibilities to do the same thing in different ways which takes less memory cosumptions.
Now i am using this code.

```
Resources r = ShowFullImage.this.getResources();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.col);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
     byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
     String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
     return temp;
}
```

Here is the reverse procedure for converting string to bitmap but string should Base64 encoding

```
/**
 * @param encodedString
 * @return bitmap (from given string)
 */
public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
   try {
      byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
      Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
      return bitmap;
   } catch(Exception e) {
      e.getMessage();
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: already i am using base64 format, i am looking for different one.

Comment: what is the difference between my code and your code, i am looking for different ways to convert other than using BAse64.

Comment: StringToBitMap is coming as null. Help me please.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()' on a null object reference. That's what I got from StringToBitmap

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can do it by implenment this code :

String to Bitmap :

```
 public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
    try {
        byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,
                encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Bitmap to String :

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use byteArray to send images or other data. there is no encoding and decoding require. and you have to use multipart body to send data to server..

Comment: It would be really appreciable and useful if you could share with your answer how to do the image upload with multipart body? (may be with android and server code blocks)