# How to covert String[] to Bitmap[]?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am making a project in which wallpaper will be changed after every 10 seconds
I am able to set Bitmap array to the Service class using this code

```
resized[i]=    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourbitmap, 480,800, true);
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WallService.class);
                    i.putExtra("Imagess", resized);
                    startService(i);
```

In the service class i am using this code:

```
 String[] Bits = intent.getStringArrayExtra("Imagess");
        for(int i =0; i<Bits.length;i++){

        getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(Bits[i]);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
```

It is giving error in this line The method setWallpaper(Bitmap) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (String). So what must I do so that i can set wallpapers by conerting String[] to Bitmap[]

---

Update 1:

```
Bitmap[] Bits = (Bitmap[]) intent.getExtras().getParcelableArray("Imagess");
        for(int i =0; i<Bits.length;i++){


        try {
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(Bits[i]);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Comment: May i know why my question is downvoted

Comment: How do you get "Bits" array? 
Like this: 
Bitmap[] Bits = (Bitmap[]) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArray("Imagess");
?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many ways to convert bitmap to string and vice-versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562429/how-many-ways-to-convert-bitmap-to-string-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong using this code line:

```
 String[] Bits = intent.getStringArrayExtra("Imagess");
```

You put `Parcelable[]` to intent extras, but trying to get String[].
Use:

```
Bitmap[] Bits = (Bitmap[]) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArray("Imagess");
```

**Update:**
If you init `Bits` array in `Service onStart(Intent intent, int startId)` method, then update this line:

```
Bitmap[] Bits = (Bitmap[]) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArray("Imagess");
```

to:

```
Bitmap[] Bits = (Bitmap[]) intent.getExtras().getParcelableArray("Imagess");
```

As you see, I replaced `getIntent()` method by `intent` argument from `onStart(Intent intent, int startId)` method

Comment: i updated the code above let me run this and check whether it is working and changing wallpapers

Comment: it giving exception in the line... Bitmap[] Bits = (Bitmap[]) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArray("Imagess");

Comment: by mistake i made this line comment i.putExtra("Imagess", resized);

Comment: i am not able to set wallpaper
i am getting this exception

Comment: Try using: intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("Imagess") line.