# How to cast Bitmap to string?

Tags: android, eclipse, image

I have an array of bitmaps [photo1,photo2,photo3.......] and I want to use a random bitmap from the array.Can I use it as a String  by casting a bitmap to the string and then changing the last number? Also I want that the casted String refers to the bitmap from the array.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562429/how-many-ways-to-convert-bitmap-to-string-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

You can't **cast** a Bitmap to a String, and even if you could, that makes no sense for what you want to do. If you want to get a random Bitmap from an array of Bitmaps, you can do as follows:

```
final Random rnd = new Random();
final int randomIndex = rnd.nextInt(array.length);
final Bitmap randomBitmap = array[randomIndex];
```

PS: in Java you should really be using `List`s instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String resultStr = convertBitmapToString (bmp1);

public String convertBitmapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
     byte [] b = baos.toByteArray();
     String bString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
     return bString;
}
```

You can also have a look at: [Convert String to Bitmap and Bitmap to String](http://practiceonandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/convert-string-to-bitmap-and-bitmap-to.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Quick question: why would you convert an image to string? :)

Comment: That's not what he/she is asking, read the question again ;) *"I have an array of bitmaps and I want to use a random bitmap from the array"*

Comment: @m0skit0 Seems like an XY issue

Comment: @m0skit0 He has written after that "Can I use it as a String by casting a bitmap to the string". so I answered for that :)

Comment: You didn't even read the question, only the title, did you? ;)

Comment: I did read the question :) @m0skit0

Comment: If you read the question, you would know what he's asking for: *"I want to use a random bitmap from the array"* It's the first sentence ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 There is no point in fighting over it. "I want to use a random bitmap from the array" is a statement. "Can I use it as a String by casting a bitmap to the string" seems like a question. :) That's my POV

Comment: Fight? Who's fighting? :) With *"Can I use it as a String by casting a bitmap to the string"* he/she's asking if that is a valid solution for what he/she wants, and obviously it is not.

Comment: @m0skit0 may be, its not. I am still at learning stage, so I can't know high level impacts. But I just gave an answer as per my interpretation of question. Have a good day ahead :) take care..

Answer (score 0):

Why not generate a random number to refer to an index in the array?

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(bitmaps.length);
Bitmap randomBitmap = bitmaps[randomIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect he has a map and the name of the bitmap is photo1, photo2 ...

[photo1,photo2,photo3.......]

He want a method to generate one random number and then get the bitmap from the array(map).

```
HashMap<String,Object> bitMaps= new HashMap<String,Object>();
...
Random rand = new Random();
int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(bitMaps.size());
Bitmap randomBitmap = bitmaps.get("photo"+randomIndex ) + 1;
```

Sorry if I totally misunderstand this problem.