# trying to reach mp4 file in raw folder by using String

Tags: java, android, mp4

i need to use different mp4 files dynamically in code and this is what i am trying to do :

```
    String video_name = "event_"+subCategoryClicked+currentPage;
    String videoFile = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/"+ video_name;
    Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFile,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    System.out.println(thumbnail);
    eventInfoImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

i have double checked that there is a file named event_bloodtest1.mp4 in raw folder i suspect that the error is the path to raw folder. Its easier to find it with resource int ID but then i don't know how to get it dynamically

thx in advance=)!

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically? there are several video files in raw folder or you are changing the video file keeping name as the same?

Comment: yes there will be like 100 files :P with different "subCategoryClicked" example
event_bloodtest1
event_bloodtest2
event_bloodtest3

event_hospital1

event_doctor1
event_doctor2

Comment: so you wanna iterate between the files with different names in a specific folder?

Comment: yes depending on which category and page the user clicks on there should show different animations in the image view

Comment: I already do this with text Strings and Images in drawable folder but now i need a String to convert to Bitmap that's the problem

Comment: Have you checked this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562429/how-many-ways-to-convert-bitmap-to-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: the problem is i never get any bitmap.
With standard .png i can do this:

       int resourceId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("event_"+subCategoryClicked+currentPage, "drawable", getPackageName());

        eventInfoImage.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);

But with mp4 file i need to convert it to bitmap and i can't do that with resourceID (for what i know)

because the method requires a String and the String i provide:

"android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/"+ video_name;

returns null so i guess the path is wrong..